# Prevent code injection in sh from busybox http daemon

Tags: linux, shell, security, busybox

I have following scenario:

The httpd of busybox (https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/webserver/http.httpd ) is installed on my embedded Linux system and I call scripts from subfolder /cgi-bin/.

I call scripts and provide GET-Parameters, that are forwarded to an actual command (called in the script)(e.g. from "...?param1=hallo&param2=text" to "-param1 hallo -param2 text") .

What I want to prevent is that someone can extend my get queue to inject other commands; something like that:

```
"http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/myScript?param=1%2%26%26%2cat%20%2Fetc%2Fpasswd"
```

Which would URL-Decoded be the command Line

> param=1 && cat /etc/passwd

(What I mean by that is that it would create a command line "myApp -parameter 1 && cat /etc/passwd", so I inject a second command independent of the first one and could e.g. output the list of users in my system)

Of course the above syntax is wrong, I'm wondering how an attacker would have to write that/ if this is in general an attack scenario/ what I would have to filter to prevent such requests. Is && and ; filtering enough?

I'm not sure, what I should search for, so any hints are very welcome.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is generally referred to as *stringification* in the programming world. It's when you take an object and convert that object to a string.

In this case what you want to do is to take data into a variable and make sure that any potentially malicious code injected from an uncontrolled source as data is turned into a string (or do other things like reporting with it) before it can accidentally be executed.

Your example does not specify what language your CGI scripts are written in, such as `perl`, `ruby`, `shell`, or something else. Based on your concerns around `&& cat /etc/passwd` as an example of a malicious activity, it sounds like you want to prevent *shell code injection* which is a form of *arbitrary code execution*. There are a number of special character symbols that can cause accidental *arbitrary code execution* in `shell` language, so I would filter out anything that is not numeric for the parameters.

This can easily be done with a simple `egrep` command and an *or clause* (`||`) as so:

```
param1=$(echo $param1 |egrep '^[0-9]$') || param1=""
```